# Problem with showing flowdocument in wpf MVVM

Tags: wpf, textbox, flowdocument

i have a textbox, and i have this xaml in it :

```
<FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph>Welk alternatief gebruik is er met een EN poort mogelijk ? <LineBreak />Flexibele inverter<LineBreak />Doorlaatfilter<LineBreak />Samensteller<LineBreak />Opteller<LineBreak /></Paragraph></FlowDocument>
```

now my question is simple, how do i show this nicely in a flowdocument, so how do i show this in my view, without all this xaml stuff (tags) in it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, all you have to do is put it in a `RichTextBox`:

```
<RichTextBox>
  <FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph>Welk alternatief gebruik is er met een EN poort mogelijk ? <LineBreak />Flexibele inverter<LineBreak />Doorlaatfilter<LineBreak />Samensteller<LineBreak />Opteller<LineBreak /></Paragraph></FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```